# Difference between logical_and vs "&" for comparing 2 boolean arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to compare 2 boolean arrays as below

```
# Create arrays
import numpy as np
my_house = np.array([18.0, 20.0, 10.75, 9.50])

# my_house greater than 18.5 and smaller than 10
print(np.logical_and(my_house > 18.5, my_house < 10))
```

What is the difference between^^ and below

```
# Create arrays
import numpy as np
my_house = np.array([18.0, 20.0, 10.75, 9.50])
a=my_house > 18.5
b=my_house < 10

# my_house greater than 18.5 and smaller than 10
print(a&b)
```

The outputs I get are the same.
What is the benefit of 1st over 2nd? And when should one prefer the 1st over 2nd?

Comment: What's the difference between `np.add` and `+`?  `np.multiply` and `*`?  `np.matmul` and `@`?  ufunc function versus equivalent operator.  Obviously the function allows you to provide more parameters.

Comment: @hpaulj, Ohk more  parameters. got it. Foolish me didn't  think of this:)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference, but it won't surface when the arguments are boolean arrays as in your example.

`&` is the `bitwise_and`, which is not the same as the `logical_and`.

The `bitwise_and` is only defined for arrays of int-like `dtype` and does what its name suggests, it applies the boolean and to each pair of corresponding bits between its arguments, resulting in an int-like of the same type:

```
a=np.arange(5)
b=np.arange(5,10)

np.bitwise_and(a,b)
# array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0])
a&b
# array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0])
```

`logical_and` first coerces its operands to bool element-by-element and then applies the boolean and resulting in a boolean array:

```
np.logical_and(a,b)
# array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

There is in practice one quirk to keep in mind. You will often see `&` where `logical_and` would make more sense. The reason is that there is no operator overload for `logical_and`; one might expect `and` but, unfortunately, python IIRC will automatically coerce the operands of `and` to bool, so `numpy`'s element-by-element semantics cannot be implemented that way. As mentioned at the top of this post: as long as the operand arrays are boolean, `logical_and` and `bitwise_and` give the same result, so users including myself typically cannot resist the convenience of writing `&` instead of `logical_and`.